# Write a function to find the key for the particular value in python?

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary

I was writing the program of method `find_key_for_value` to retrieve the key for the value return none

```
class my_dict(dict):    
    def add(self, key, value):
        self.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

    def remove_key(self, key):
        del self[key]

    def remove_value(self, key, value):
        if value in self[key]:
            self[key].remove(value)

    def find_key_for_value(self,value_to_find):
        for key, value in dict_obj.items():
            if value == value_to_find:
                return key
                #return [key for key,value in dict_obj.items() if value == value_to_find] 


dict_obj = my_dict()
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value1')
dict_obj.add('key2', 'value9')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value3')
```

find the key to print

```
dict_obj.find_key_for_value('value1')
```

desired out  `key1`

Comment: value is a list in your example ... so i think you want `if value_to_find in value`

Comment: like someone pointed out, use `self` instead of `dict_object` in the method

Comment: If you find yourself looking up values to determine the key, your dictionary is backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm looks correct, you have a typo:

```
    def find_key_for_value(self,value_to_find):
        # note the change from dict_obj to self here
        for key, value in self.items():
            if value == value_to_find:
                return key
```

Comment: That said you need to correct your implementation of add as pointed out in the comment above as well.

Answer (score 0):

You dict value is a list. So you have to check if your value_to_find is within this list.

```
def find_key_for_value(self,value_to_find):
        for key, value in self.items():
            if value_to_find in value:
                return key
```

or if your dict might become huge or a value can have multiple keys use:

```
def find_key_for_value(self,value_to_find):
        return list(filter(lambda key: value_to_find in self[key], self.keys()))
```